# Inversion of control in Unity?

Tags: unity, dependency-injection

I am semi-experienced .NET developer who has just began working with Unity. I am trying to decide on how to make IoC work in Unity 4.X ( I have not yet tested anything), and I wonder what are the good ways of achieving it.

[This post and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309750/ninject-with-unity3d) states that Ninject won't work with Unity, however it is old. Is it still true? If yes, what are other means of achieving IoC in Unity ?

Edit 1 : I am targeting mainly Windows platform. So I don't need platform interoperability, I just need it to work.

Comment: IIRC Ninject works fine in Mono, so you should be able to use it as a service locator at least.  You won't be able to do dependency injection with the classes that are instantiated by Unity, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to look at StrangeIOC.

http://strangeioc.github.io/strangeioc/

It's meant for Unity.  The project has been under active development for quite some time, and I keep meaning to check it out, but as of yet I haven't so I can't give you the personal recommendation.  But it sounds like exactly like what you want.

Comment: This is definitely what you want. I've been using it since its release (essentially) and it's very well put together with great documentation. I honestly can't see myself developing a game in Unity without it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is something that so far has exceeded my expectations :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but nobody did managed to run it under unity: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ios-dependency-injection-framework-suggestions.119909/ but can be very outdated. Nonetheless, try to post your question to UnityAnswers, where will you get more likely a proper answer.

Comment: UnityAnwsers have failed me - http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/719987/inversion-of-control-in-unity-does-ninject-work-ar.html .

Comment: http://u3d.as/content/thirdmotion/strange-io-c/4Xj this should help you, if Ninject won't work :)